# Now my query returns the plant if there is no data but

Tags: sql, reporting-services

It's summing everything for all rows.

[image]

and here is the query:

[image]

I'm wondering if the problem lies in my WHERE clause? I'm still very new to this and with a WHERE clause this big it can get screwy quick.

Thanks in advance!

Aaron

Comment: Someone who's been around for 3 months and asked 5 questions should have some idea how to put code into a post.

Comment: You can always paste **the actual text**, I'm sure you have privilege for that!

Comment: Have you tried using a `GROUP BY` clause?  Can you simplify your query to isolate the problem you are having, and explain in more detail?

Comment: BTW, I already read this 3 times. What's the problem again? I can't tell.

Comment: JNK.. .I tried to on my last question and it didn't work so I had to go this route. Sorry, but I don't post a lot so I'm still learning the ropes... Mellamokb, I'll try that. thanks. Adrian, my orig prob was that my plant name wasn't showing even if there were no results. So now it shows the plant but as you can see, it's summing then data for all plants and each plant should have its own results.

Comment: I wonder what is BIG about the WHERE clause. Is it because they are in caps ...?

Comment: Thanks Eddy.. Meant my FROM clause.. yes it's a Monday. And if this is a bad question everyone then just say so... If I knew how to delete it and start over I would

Comment: I'm trying to determine why it's giving me the same data for all of the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's giving you the same numbers from each row because of how you have the `JOIN`s structured.

1. You `SELECT` the plant from pinv
2. You `JOIN` from `pinv` -> `pf` based on DATE **(not plant)**
3. You `JOIN` to `ppf` based on the date in `pf` **(not plant)**
4. You `JOIN` to `prc` based on the date in `pf` **(not plant)**
5. You `JOIN` to `dpt` based on `department_number` **(not plant)**
6. You `JOIN` to `pls` based on `pf` (which again was linked to plant table by **DATE**) **(not plant)**
7. You filter in the `WHERE` clause based again on **DATE**

You need to link the production numbers directly to the plant to get data specific to the plant.  I think you are basically aggregating here without a `GROUP BY`.  Any real insight will require you to post your table structure and relationships.

Comment: Thank you. And I wish I could post the tables/relationships but if you think I screwed this simple thing up, those would be even worse! Our company is having them audited by MSFT to clean them up. I'll work on my joins and see if that doesn't fix it. Thanks again.